# Is there any function other than identity function whose domain and co-domain are same?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For example let’s assume a function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $ now my question is can we find a function $f$ other than $f(x) =x$ Which satisfies the above situation?And if we can find it what are some of the examples?

My main issue is I have seen (or can imagine) $f(x)=x$ as the only function whose domain and co-domain are same. Is there any other function with that property?

Comment: Why not $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: How about the constant function $f(x) = 0$? or $f(x) = 1-x$

Comment: Anyway, there are literally infinitely many examples:  just draw them.

Comment: Does all of them have something in common? (Except the condition which I have asked for)

Comment: No, they can vary wildly.  The only thing they have in common is that their graphs live in the unit square.

Comment: Can they only be polynomial function?

Comment: @Knight Why *would* they have to be polynomial functions? What about $f(x)=\vert\sin(x)\vert$? Or something discontinuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randall's comment "draw them" is exactly what you should do: rather than approach this from the perspective of looking for specific formulas corresponding to such functions, convince yourself via pictures that lots of them exist in the first place. This will really demystify the situation.

Specifically, draw a unit square, and then any curve going from the left side to the right side which satisfies the vertical line test (so it actually represents a function). You can draw a curve with corners, or even worse with "gaps" - like $f(x)=1$ for $x<{1\over 2}$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge {1\over 2}$. (Granted, that last one stretches the meaning of "curve" a bit, but it's still a valid way to get a function.)

So there's a lot of stuff you can get this way.

Now this won't even get you **all** the relevant functions - it will miss "impossible-to-draw" functions like [the Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) (restricted to the unit interval) - but you can get a lot this way, and it should convince you that this isn't really a big restriction at all.

---

In fact, keep in mind that the codomain of a function **can be bigger than** its range. In particular, given any function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ with $Y\subseteq X$ we can always "rephrase" $f$ as a function $\hat{f}: X\rightarrow X$ which has the same values as $f$ but with a different codomain declared. But this can be a confusing point initially, so it's worth understanding the previous stuff first.